# RiveScript gives an error for python object macros

Tags: python-3.x, rivescript

Is it possible to access the object macros internally in RiveScript? I'm bit confused with that.
I have defined the following script:

```
> object small python
  return "4"
< object

+ small
- <call>small</call>
```

Which gives me an error when I enter `small`:

```
error: [ERR: Object Not Found]
```

Comment: I've tried to make the question a bit more understandable.

Answer (score 1):

The definition of the `object` seems to be ok, but you are probably running it from https://play.rivescript.com/ or https://www.rivescript.com/try, which only allow JavaScript or CoffeeScript (see the [about page](https://play.rivescript.com/about#how-it-works)).

You can use [rivescript-python](https://github.com/aichaos/rivescript-python) to run the code, which you can install by:

```
pip install rivescript
```

Then put your rivescript in a file (`.rive`), for example, in `helloworld.rive`.

Then in python:

```
from rivescript import RiveScript
bot = RiveScript()
bot.load_directory('.') # set your directory where the .rive file(s) is/are
bot.sort_replies()
```

Now you can use `bot.reply` to get the answer for a certain input:

```
>>> bot.reply('localuser','small')
'4'
```

---

*Edit*: I have tested this code on Ubuntu 14.04 with Python 3.4.3 and Python 2.7.12 and rivescript 1.14.4.

Comment: I used pip install rivescript to install.. but then its not working.

Comment: object macros is not getting called. I m getting "Object Not Found" error.

Answer (score 1):

make a  space after the object name just like that

```
- <call>small  </call>
```

Comment: Here are some guidelines for [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).  This provided answer may be correct, but it could benefit from an explanation.  Code only answers are not considered "good" answers.  From [review](https://stackoverflow.com/review).